# Deploying a community with a managed package?

Tags: community, managed-package

I'm developing an app that I hope will be distributed as a Managed Package.  I'm developing using SFDX, a dev edition org with a namespace and a partner edition org with dev hub on.

The Managed Package needs to have a community in it.

As I've been developing the app, when I push the code to a new scratch org I've been having to first actually create a community with the same name before I push my code or I get the errors:

Default_Navigation: In field: Network - no Network named Members found,
cbMembers: Network not found for the CustomBrand : cbMembers,
Members: In field: Name - no Network named Members found,
Members1: No Network named Members found, needed to associate this Site Members1, which is 0DM3F000000DeVw

I have found no workaround, anytime I see someone with a similar issue, the resolution is to first create a community in that org.

Now that I'm trying to create my the first version of my managed pacakge, this error is preventing me from being able to create a version using: force:package:version:create

Is it actually possible to include a community in a managed package?

Comment: According to the metadata coverage, it is not possible to include community in managed package -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/49

Answer (score 3):

Communities are not packageable yet in 2GP packages. It is recommended you package everything as a template using [Lightning Bolt Technology](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_export_overview.htm&type=5).

It is preferred you have it as a 1GP extension package.I would keep communities specific metadata in an extension package than making it part of one package.

> Lightning Bolt for Salesforce lets you quickly build and distribute industry-specific Lightning Bolt Solutions to jump-start new org capabilities. Save time by building once and then reusing.

Comment: issue resolved or still exisitng ? I am facing same issue

Comment: This is still a limitation! You can use bolt to package themes and pages in 1GP